# Pandas: concat multiple .csv files and return Dataframe with columns of the same name aggregated

Tags: python, pandas, csv, concatenation

I have 100 csv files. Each file contains columns that may or may not be in the other .csv files. I need to merge all of the csv files into one and sum all columns that have the same column name. Below is an example with two csv files, but imagine it can go up to 100 csv files:

**first csv file:**

```
 User  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 ....colX
 A     1    1     1    2    6        5
 B     4    5     6    7    23       6
 C     4    6     1    2     4       4
```

**second csv file**

```
User  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 ....colY
 A     1    1     5    3    2       3
 B     20   4     3    9    6       4 
 C     2    1     4    3    4       1
```

**Result DataFrame**

```
User   col1   col2    col3   col4   col5 ....colX colY
 A     1+1    1+1     1+5    2+3    6+2       5    3
 B     4+20   5+4     6+3    7+9    23+6      6    4
 C     4+2    6+1     1+4    2+3    4+4       4    1
```

I have tried doing the following to combine the csv, but columns are not aggregating.

```
csvArray = []
for x in range(1,101): 
   csvArray.append(pd.read_csv("myCsv"+str(x)+".csv"))

full_df = pd.concat(csvArray).fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create index by `User` column and use `sum` by first level:

```
csvArray = []
for x in range(1,101): 
   csvArray.append(pd.read_csv("myCsv{}.csv".format(x), index_col=['User']))
```

Or:

```
csvArray = [pd.read_csv("myCsv{}.csv".format(x), index_col=['User']) for x in range(1,101)]
```

---

```
full_df = pd.concat(csvArray).fillna(0).sum(level=0).reset_index()
```

In your solution should aggregate by `User` column:

```
full_df = pd.concat(csvArray).fillna(0).groupby('User', as_index=False).sum()
```

Comment: @user5844628 - You are welcome! If my answer was helpful, don't forget accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try:

```
data = pd.DataFrame()
for x in range(1, 101):
    df = pd.read_csv('mycsv'+str(x)+'.csv').set_index('User')
    data = data.add(df, fill_value = 0).fillna(0)
```